# Ansible: How to preserve facts across executions?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I am trying to understand how to get facts to be preserved across multiple playbook runs.
I have something like this:

```yaml
- name: Host Check
  block:
  - name: Host Check | Obtain System UUID
    shell:
      cmd: >
        dmidecode --string system-uuid
        | head -c3
    register: uuid

  - name: Host Check | Verify EC2
    set_fact:
      is_ec2: "{{ uuid.stdout == 'ec2' }}"
      cacheable: yes
```

That chunk of code saves `is_ec2` as a fact and is executed by a bigger playbook, let's say `setup.yml`:

```sh
ansible-playbook -i cloud_inventory.ini setup.yml
```

But then if I wanted to run another playbook, let's say `test.yml` and tried to access `is_ec2` (on the same host), I get the following error:

```sh
fatal: [factTest]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'is_ec2' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/path/to/playbooks/test.yml': line 9, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n    - name: Print isEC2\n      ^ here\n"}
```

I am a little confused because while I read this is possible in the docs, I can't get it to work.

> This boolean converts the variable into an actual 'fact' which will also be added to the fact cache, if fact caching is enabled.
> Normally this module creates 'host level variables' and has much higher precedence, this option changes the nature and precedence (by 7 steps) of the variable created. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable
> This actually creates 2 copies of the variable, a normal 'set_fact' host variable with high precedence and a lower 'ansible_fact' one that is available for persistance via the facts cache plugin. This creates a possibly confusing interaction with meta: clear_facts as it will remove the 'ansible_fact' but not the host variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve it!

While there was nothing wrong with the code above, in order to make it work I needed to enable fact caching and specify the plugin I wanted to use. This can be done in the `ansible.cfg` file by adding these lines:

```
fact_caching = jsonfile
fact_caching_connection = /path/to/cache/directory/where/a/json/will/be/saved
```

After that I was able to access those cached facts across executions.

I was curious to see what the JSON file would look like and it seems like it has the facts that you can gather from the `setup` module and the cached facts:

```json
...
...

    "ansible_virtualization_tech_host": [],
    "ansible_virtualization_type": "kvm",
    "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python3",
    "gather_subset": [
        "all"
    ],
    "is_ec2": true,
    "module_setup": true
}
```

Comment: Right, [Caching Facts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#caching-facts) and [Cache Plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/cache.html) are the answer.